# 2 NICS using Windows Server 2012 as "gate"

Tags: active-directory, dhcp, windows-server-2012, remote-access

I want to use my windows server as a gateway and DHCP for my local network. It have 2 NICs where one will be connected to the internet and the other to my local network. There are no router on the other side only clients and a switch.

I have speend 8+ hours on this so far, and are no further then i was when i begain. 
So far i have figured out that i need to setup DirectAccess and a DHCP on my server, is this correct or is there an easier way? 
And do DirectAccess require a Domain Controller or can i set it up without?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your server with the Remote Access (formerly known as RRAS (Routing and Remote Access)) role. In there you define your public and private networks.

Technet has all the info you should need: [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458974.aspx)
I also found [this step-by-step](http://www.falconitservices.com/support/KB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77) instruction, but don't follow each step blindly.

DirectAccess, on the other hand, is a technology for compter-based VPNs allowing your computers outside the LAN to communicate with defined resources on the LAN without the user having to do anything. It is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, reinstalling my server now to get a clean canvas to begin with, i will let you know.